Ansible custom folder structure

I have placed all the folders related Ansible inside AnsibleDeploymentScripts folder in a github repo. When I sync project in Ansible it is showing error like below. Is there any way to provide root folder path while sync project.? If I place roles folder outside then it is working fine.
[WARNING]: Unable to find
'/var/lib/awx/projects/XXXXXXXXXX/roles' in expected paths
(use -vvvvv to see paths)
